# In Kivy, is it possible to draw on a layer over an image with pinch and zoom capability?

Tags: graphics, kivy, touch, kivy-language

So I'm new to Kivy (just started today), but I'm sorta familiar with graphical programming given I've done some Processing in the past for Arduino interfaces. My situation is this:

1. I want to load an image.
2. I want to be able to draw on a new layer OVER image WITH the ability to pinch and zoom but keeping the new layer locked to the image in regards to position / rotation.
3. I then want to be able to save the new layer as its own image.
4. Ideally, I want to be able to apply Gaussian blurs to this new layer using matrix math.

[I've attached a simplified drawing of what I'm hoping to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ddj.png)

I think I keep getting confused by the idea of the canvas and how it's used in Kivy, and most of my coding experience is based within the mechatronics realm. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, and it shouldn't be very hard. However, there are quite a few individual details you're wanting to bring together, so it's not easy to provide a single simple example.

In general terms, you can use a Scatter for the pinch to zoom stuff (although this isn't the only way), and all the stuff to do with loading/drawing/saving images is doable using the standard Kivy APIs for these things.

I would suggest that the best way forward would be to start with a minimal example, see if you can make an Image that you can manipulate using a Scatter. After that you can add the extra drawing layer, and work out how to save it. This will be a good proof of concept to then go back and add in the general functionality of the app.

You may find it more convenient to ask about this on the Kivy discord channel, as this is a better forum for interactive discussion.